# How to convert Numpy to Parquet without using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, parquet

The traditional way to save a numpy object to parquet is to use Pandas as an intermediate. However, I am working with a lot of data, which doesn't fit in Pandas without crashing my enviroment because in Pandas, the data takes up a lot of RAM.

I need to save to Parquet because I am working with variable length arrays in numpy, so for that parquet actually saves to a smaller space than .npy or .hdf5 .

The following code is a minimal example that downloads a small chunk of my data, and converts between pandas objects and numpy objects to measure how much RAM they consume, and save to npy and parquet files to see how much disk space they take.

```
# Download sample file, about 10 mbs

from sys import getsizeof
import requests
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

def download_file_from_google_drive(id, destination):
    URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"

    session = requests.Session()

    response = session.get(URL, params = { 'id' : id }, stream = True)
    token = get_confirm_token(response)

    if token:
        params = { 'id' : id, 'confirm' : token }
        response = session.get(URL, params = params, stream = True)

    save_response_content(response, destination)    

def get_confirm_token(response):
    for key, value in response.cookies.items():
        if key.startswith('download_warning'):
            return value

    return None

def save_response_content(response, destination):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 32768

    with open(destination, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE):
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)

download_file_from_google_drive('1-0R28Yhdrq2QWQ-4MXHIZUdZG2WZK2qR', 'sample.pkl')

sampleDF = pd.read_pickle('sample.pkl')

sampleDF.to_parquet( 'test1.pqt', compression = 'brotli', index = False )

# Parquet file takes up little space 
os.path.getsize('test1.pqt')
```

> 6594712

```
getsizeof(sampleDF)
```

> 22827172

```
sampleDF['totalCites2'] = sampleDF['totalCites2'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))

#RAM reduced if the variable length batches are in numpy
getsizeof(sampleDF)
```

> 22401764

```
#Much less RAM as a numpy object 
sampleNumpy = sampleDF.values
getsizeof(sampleNumpy)
```

> 112

```
# Much more space in .npy form 
np.save( 'test2.npy', sampleNumpy) 
os.path.getsize('test2.npy')
```

> 20825382

```
# Numpy savez. Not as good as parquet 
np.savez_compressed( 'test3.npy', sampleNumpy )
os.path.getsize('test3.npy.npz')
```

> 9873964

Comment: That 112 number is meaningless.  In general `sys.getsizeof` is not a good measure of memory use.

Comment: What would be a better way to measure the memory use?

Comment: For `ndarray` `nbytes`.  That's just the number of elements times the size of each element (typically 4-8bytes).  A `DataFrame` might store its data in a similar sized array.   But if you have arrays of arrays or lists (object dtype) then you have to take into account the size of those objects.  There's no one number or measure; you have to understand how the data object is structured.

Comment: The array that is just 112, actually shares data memory with the dataframe that it is derived from.  The 112 just measures the 'object' with attributes like shape and strides, and doesn't measure the underlying data buffer size (because it does not own it).

Comment: If there are many repeated values in columns then pandas sparse data structures may help - see  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html for documentation of `pandas.SparseArray` and others

Comment: Using your notebook I `pickle.load` the `sample.pkl` file.  The result was a `DataFrame`.  In other words, given the source, you can't bypass pandas.  That's the version with lists in the second column.  Your `apply` command converts those to arrays, though with lengths of 5 to100 that doesn't seem to make much difference.  It's an object dtype column.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can read/write numpy arrays to parquet directly using Apache Arrow (pyarrow), which is also the underlying backend to parquet in pandas.
Note that parquet is a **tabular** format, so creating some table is still necessary.

```
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa

np_arr = np.array([1.3, 4.22, -5], dtype=np.float32)
pa_table = pa.table({"data": np_arr})
pa.parquet.write_table(pa_table, "test.parquet")
```

refs:
[numpy to pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/numpy.html),
[pyarrow.parquet.write_table](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html#pyarrow.parquet.write_table)

Answer (score 4):

Parquet format can be written using `pyarrow`, the correct import syntax is:

`import pyarrow.parquet as pq` so you can use `pq.write_table`. Otherwise using  `import pyarrow as pa, pa.parquet.write_table` will return: `AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'parquet'`.

Pyarrow requires the data to be organized columns-wise, which means in the case of `numpy` multidimensional arrays, you need to assign each dimension to a specific field in the `parquet` column.

```py
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq


ndarray = np.array(
    [
        [4.96266477e05, 4.55342071e06, -1.03240000e02, -3.70000000e01, 2.15592864e01],
        [4.96258372e05, 4.55344875e06, -1.03400000e02, -3.85000000e01, 2.40120775e01],
        [4.96249387e05, 4.55347732e06, -1.03330000e02, -3.47500000e01, 2.70718535e01],
    ]
)

ndarray_table = pa.table(
    {
        "X": ndarray[:, 0],
        "Y": ndarray[:, 1],
        "Z": ndarray[:, 2],
        "Amp": ndarray[:, 3],
        "Ang": ndarray[:, 4],
    }
)

pq.write_table(ndarray_table, "ndarray.parquet")
```

Comment: Or you can just use           'import pyarrow.parquet', 
'import pyarrow as pa' combo